# overloaded method match for ... has invalid argument

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures

```
 decimal dpmo = notMet + notMet * 100;    
 decimal ans = Summary_Matrics_Client.getall(dpmo);
```

> here I am calling LINQ function

```
public static decimal getall(ref decimal? number)
{
    var sigma = from p in db.getDPMO(ref number)
                select p.Sigma.Value;
    return sigma.SingleOrDefault();

}
```

> getDPMO is stored procedure which is :

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE getDPMO

    (
    @number decimal OUTPUT
    )

AS
    select 
min(Sigma_Value) as Sigma 
    from 
Sigma_Table 
    where Defect_Rate < @number

    RETURN
```

> I am getting error:  (ref? decimal) has invalid argument while calling getall()

Comment: You probably need to add `ref` to call `getall(dpmo)` before parameter.

Comment: I tried but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the mistake :

```
decimal ans = Summary_Matrics_Client.getall(dpmo);
```

you need to pass it by reference as you have defined in the `getall` method signatures that it will take parameter by reference, so you need to add `ref` keyword in call:

```
decimal ans = Summary_Matrics_Client.getall(ref dpmo);
```

By the way you don't actually need to pass it by reference, there is no need to, just make it simple like, though i can see in the implementation of `getall` you are again passing by reference which might be the case that the `getDPMO` expects parameter with `ref` keyword i.e. (pas by reference) :

```
public static decimal getall(decimal? number)
```

and then calling side will be as you wrote right now :

```
decimal ans = Summary_Matrics_Client.getall(dpmo);
```

Comment: what if we have null value for Sigma in getall() LINQ function? because I am getting : "Nullable object must have a value"  error for some null value

Comment: in your stored procedure the parameter is not nullable, but from c# side you are passing nullable, so when it is null it will cause stored procedure call to fail, as it does not expects null coming, you probably need to make stored procedure parameter optional

Comment: Thank you Ehsan Sajjad!!